# Failed to resolve parameter [javax.sql.DataSource dataSource] for h2 database in Java 17 Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, h2, datasource, junit5, java-17

I am trying to upgrade a project from Java 11 and Spring Boot 2.7.3 to Java 17 and Spring Boot 3.0.6. H2 db is used for Junit 5 testing. Many of the test cases are failing - Datasource is not getting created. All other dependencies have been upgraded to the latest versions. Below are the errors from the stack when I run a debug on the test class.

19-06-2023 22:36:06.951 ERROR Application run failed ## () o.s.boot.SpringApplication
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Class org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider does not implement the requested interface jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider

```
          org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
```

at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider does not implement the requested interface jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider

org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: Failed to resolve parameter [javax.sql.DataSource dataSource] in constructor [public se.billing.customer.file.readers.VoipCustomerItemReaderTest(javax.sql.DataSource)]: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@54087bdb testClass = se.billing.customer.file.readers.VoipCustomerItemReaderTest, locations = [], classes = [se.billing.customer.file.readers.Application], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = ["test"], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [[ImportsContextCustomizer@587f6634 key =

```
 org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@4b3fa0b3, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@23202fce, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@c7e8a7d9\], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null\]


    org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@7d598265, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@4bbf6d0e, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@9da1, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@4b3fa0b3, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@23202fce, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@c7e8a7d9\], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null\]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:142)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.getApplicationContext(SpringExtension.java:283)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.resolveParameter(SpringExtension.java:269)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ParameterResolutionUtils.resolveParameter(ParameterResolutionUtils.java:136)
    ... 57 more


   

My pom.xml looks as follows:

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.6</version>
  </parent>

 <properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
 </properties>
    
 <dependencies>
    <!-- Lombok -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- jmx -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
      <artifactId>jolokia-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- Spring Boot admin -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- Databases -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
      <version>23.2.0.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- Logback -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
      <version>7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- swagger -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- swagger -->
    <!-- test !-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-integration-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-integration-test-support</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>  
    
    
    


    application-test.yaml:

    spring:
      datasource:
        url: jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=Oracle;INIT= (some DDL actions)
        driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
        username: sa
        password:
    h2:
      console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2-console
    jpa:
      database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
      hibernate.ddl-auto: none
      properties:
    hibernate:
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
      show_sql: true
      format_sql: true
      jooq.sql-dialect: H2
    sql:
      init:
      platform: h2
    schema-locations: classpath:/schema.sql
```

The test class is as follows:

```
    package se.billing.customer.file.readers;

    import java.math.BigDecimal;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.time.LocalDateTime;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Optional;
    import org.jooq.DSLContext;
    import org.jooq.SQLDialect;
    import org.jooq.impl.DSL;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
    import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers;
    import org.mockito.Mockito;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
    import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext.ClassMode;
    import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
    import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

    ### some internal dependencies

    import javax.sql.DataSource;

    @Transactional
    @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
    @SpringBootTest
    @ActiveProfiles("test")
    @DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
    @AutoConfigureMockMvc
    @ComponentScan({"some path"})

    class VoipCustomerItemReaderTest extends TestData {

    private final DataSource dataSource;
    private final DSLContext dsl;
    private PhoneNrTypeRecord phoneNrTypeRecord;
    private PhoneNrRecord phoneNrRecord;
    private VoipCustomerItemReader voipCustomerItemReader;
    private boolean isSeparatedMaster;

    @MockBean
    LegalInformationService legalInformationService;

    @Autowired
    public VoipCustomerItemReaderTest(DataSource dataSource) {
        super(dataSource);
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.dsl = DSL.using((Connection) dataSource, SQLDialect.H2);
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void beforeTest() {
        initRecords();
        storeRecords();
        voipCustomerItemReader =
        new VoipCustomerItemReader(10000, (DataSource) dataSource, legalInformationService);
        Mockito.reset(legalInformationService);
    }

    @Override
    public void initSeparatedMasterRecord(BigDecimal lastBillRunId) {
       isSeparatedMaster = true;
       initRecords();
       billAccountRecord.setBillAccountHierarchyId(null);
       billAccountRecord.setLastBillRunId(lastBillRunId);
    }

    @Override
    public void initRecords() {
        if (isSeparatedMaster) {
            super.initRecords(CustomerConstants.TERMINATED_CONTRACT_STATE);
        } else {
        super.initRecords();
    }

    phoneNrTypeRecord = dsl.newRecord(PHONE_NR_TYPE);
    phoneNrTypeRecord.setPhoneNrTypeId(BigDecimal.ONE);
    .....
    .....

    }

    @Override
    public void storeRecords() {
        super.storeRecords();
        phoneNrTypeRecord.store();
        phoneNrRecord.store();
    }

    @AfterEach
    void afterEachTest() {
        dsl.dropSchema(somecode);
        dsl.dropSchema(somecode);
        dsl.dropSchema(somecode);
    }

    @Test
    void read() {
    List\<CustomerModel\> result = voipCustomerItemReader.read();
    voipCustomerItemReader.close();
    assertTrue(result.isEmpty());

    billAccountRecord.setLastExported(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-02-02T00:00:00"));
    billAccountRecord.store();
    ....
    ....

    }

    @Test
    void map() {
        billAccountRecord.setUseSparAddress(BigDecimal.ONE);
        billAccountRecord.setLastExported(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-02-02T00:00:00"));
        billAccountRecord.store();
        phoneNrRecord.setUpdated(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-02-03T00:00:00"));
        phoneNrRecord.store();
        .......
    }

    @Test
    void mapEnterprise() {
    billAccountRecord.setUseSparAddress(BigDecimal.ONE);
    billAccountRecord.setLastExported(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-02-02T00:00:00"));
    billAccountRecord.store();

        customerTypeDetailRecord.setLedger(ENTERPRISE_CUSTOMER_LEDGER);
        customerTypeDetailRecord.store();
    
        phoneNrRecord.setUpdated(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-02-03T00:00:00"));
        phoneNrRecord.store();
        List<CustomerModel> customerModels = voipCustomerItemReader.read();
        voipCustomerItemReader.close();
        ....

    }

    @Test
    void mapEmptyExternalIndividual() {

        when(legalInformationService.getLegalInformation(ArgumentMatchers.any()))
            .thenReturn(Optional.empty());
        billAccountRecord.setUseSparAddress(BigDecimal.ONE);
        .....
        Assertions.assertNull(customerModel.getCoAddress());
        Assertions.assertNull(customerModel.getStreet());
        .....

    }

    @Test
    void mapExternalWrongLedger() {
    when(legalInformationService.getLegalInformation(ArgumentMatchers.any()))
    .thenReturn(Optional.of(TestUtil.buildLegalAddress()));
    customerTypeDetailRecord.setLedger(ENTERPRISE_CUSTOMER_LEDGER);
    customerTypeDetailRecord.store();

        billAccountRecord.setUseSparAddress(BigDecimal.ONE);
        billAccountRecord.setLastExported(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-02-02T00:00:00"));
        billAccountRecord.store();
        phoneNrRecord.setUpdated(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-02-03T00:00:00"));
        phoneNrRecord.store();
        List<CustomerModel> customerModels = voipCustomerItemReader.read();
        voipCustomerItemReader.close();
        CustomerModel customerModel = customerModels.get(0);
        .....

    }

    @Test
    void mapExternalNotUsingSpar() {

        when(legalInformationService.getLegalInformation(ArgumentMatchers.any()))
            .thenReturn(Optional.of(TestUtil.buildLegalAddress()));
    
        billAccountRecord.setUseSparAddress(BigDecimal.ZERO);
        billAccountRecord.setLastExported(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-02-02T00:00:00"));
        billAccountRecord.store();
        ....

        }
    }
```

I have tried adding latest hibernate-core and jakarta-persistence-api depenedencies but did not help. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you solved this? Having a similar issue with Java 11>21 upgrade and related.